# How to set library path for CTest when building package with dpkg-builpackage?

Tags: cmake, dpkg, ctest

I'm using CTest in my project. I added simple script to run tests as `POST_BUILD`. Everything works fine when i build project with `make`.

The interesting part starts when I'm building package with `dpkg-buildpackage`. CTest seems to look for libraries in system directories instead of using a currently built one. Is there a way to tell `CTest` or `dpkg-buildpackage` to use a currently built library while executing tests?

CMake macro i use:

```
add_executable(example tests/example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example my_lib)
enable_testing()

macro(add_unit_test target test)
    list(APPEND tests ${test})
    add_test(${target} ${test})
endmacro(add_unit_test)

add_unit_test(test_example example)

add_custom_target(all_tests ALL DEPENDS ${tests})

add_custom_command(
    TARGET all_tests
    COMMENT "Run tests"
    POST_BUILD COMMAND ctest ARGS --output-on-failure
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
)
```

Comment: `CTest seems to look for libraries in system directories instead of using a currently built one.` - More likely, it is just **your environment** is configured to prefer libraries in system directories over project-local ones. Have you tried to call `example` executable directly? Which libraries are used in that case?

Comment: @Tsyvarev when i execute it directly, it use project-local libraries. Maybe i need to set some settings to debian/rules, but i just don't now what exactly i need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so i've figured it out.
Because my lib compiles in `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`, all i needed is to add 
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` prorerty to every test in project.

So macro now looks like this:

```
macro(add_unit_test target test)
    list(APPEND tests ${test})
    add_test(${target} ${test})
    set_property(TEST ${target} PROPERTY ENVIRONMENT "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
endmacro(add_unit_test)
```